Transform AVRO payload into JSON when receiving message in Citrus Kafka Endpoint
I'm doing a PoC to verify if I can use Citrus framework for automated tests that will require to check some data has been published in a Kafka Topics.

For the demo, I'm using Kotlin, also I'm using Quarkus given that I will need some features of this framework in other tests of the demo.
The test scope is for verifying integration with external kafka topic.
The Kafka topic has AVRO as value type, but its content structure is a JSON.
I have initialized the KafkaEndpoint specifying KafkaAvroDeserializer as value deserializer
I also have provided the schema registry url and credentials in the consumer properties.
I'm trying to perform a validation based in the content, using a jsonPath validation, but I'm getting an exception saying that "Failed to find proper message validator".
I'm wondering if there is a way to "convert" or "transform" the message into a JSON in order to be able to perform the validation?

Find details below:
This is a sample of message to validate:
{
  "key": "The_Message_Key",
  "value": {
    "eventId": "The_Event_Id",
    "serviceName": "fileService",
    "serviceId": "fileServiceId",
    "status": "succeeded",
    ... other fields
  }
}

This is the way that I'm initializing the KafkaEndpoint:
KafkaEndpointBuilder()
    .server("boostrap.server-1,boostrap.server-2,boostrap.server-3")
    .topic("events.topic.with.avro.values")
    .consumerProperties(consumerPropertiesMap)
    .valueDeserializer(KafkaAvroDeserializer::class.java)
    .build()

This is how I'm performing the validation
testCaseRunner.then(receive()
    .endpoint(eventsTopicEndpoint)
    .message()
    .type(MessageType.JSON)
    .validate(jsonPath()
        .expression("$.eventId", contains(file.name))))

Here is an screenshot of the Error:

I have tried changing the Deserializer to the default StringSerializer but I get similar error. I want to use the json validator that Citrus provides in order to perform verification over specific fields of the Message value.

You could wrap the Avro deserializer in another one that converts to a json object or string, otherwise Avro content structure is binary, not json. Do you not have the option to validate in other ways without type conversion?

Did you include the citrus-validation-json module as a dependency to your project?

@ChristophDeppisch yes, I have citrus-validation-json and citrus-validation-hamcrest modules as dependencies.
I could solve the issue with the approach that OneCricketeer suggested. I will publish the fix that I applied.

I implemented the solution suggested by @OneCricketeer:

Created a new Serializer that extends KafkaAvroDeserializer. The citrus-validation-json dependency from io.confluent is required.
Configured the KafkaEndpoint to use my Serializer
Also, it is required to include citrus-kafka and citrus-validation-json modules as dependencies. Also citrus-validation-hamcrest is required to use hamcrest as part of the validations over the json response.

Below are the code snippets:
KafkaEndpoint Setup:
KafkaEndpointBuilder()
    .server("boostrap.server-1,boostrap.server-2,boostrap.server-3")
    .topic("events.topic.with.avro.values")
    .consumerProperties(consumerPropertiesMap)
    .valueDeserializer(AvroToStringDeserializer::class.java)
    .build()

AvroToStringDeserializer:
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
import org.apache.kafka.common.header.Headers

class AvroToStringDeserializer : KafkaAvroDeserializer() {

    override fun deserialize(topic: String, data: ByteArray): String {
        val record = super.deserialize(topic, data) as GenericRecord

        return record.toString()
    }

    override fun deserialize(topic: String, headers: Headers, data: ByteArray): String {
        val record = super.deserialize(topic, headers, data) as GenericRecord

        return record.toString()
    }

    override fun deserialize(topic: String, data: ByteArray, schema: Schema): String {
        val record = super.deserialize(topic, data, schema) as GenericRecord

        return record.toString()
    }

    override fun deserialize(topic: String, headers: Headers, data: ByteArray, schema: Schema): String {
        val record = super.deserialize(topic, headers, data, schema) as GenericRecord

        return record.toString()
    }

}


Very nice. Note: record  can be null, so any of the toString could fail
